# Is running DSC cmdlets through CIM session on Linux require root user?

Tags: linux, powershell, dsc

I want to run DSC cmdlets, like Update-DscConfiguration and Start-DscConfiguration remotely on Linux. I want to use CIM session for that. The only way I found to do that is to enable root user on my Linux machine and then run the CIM session with this root user. As far as I know enabling root user should be avoided if possible. Is there any other way to run DSC cmdlets through CIM session on Linux rather then using root credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/lnxgettingstarted):

For “Push” mode, the user credential must be the root user on the Linux computer.

Comment: Yep, I saw that but I would like to understand why and for which DSC cmdlets this is a requirement. Actually I'm using pull mode but seems root is also required to run Udate-DscConfiguration using CIM session.